# How to check if there is a special character or number in string but not at the end of that string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Is it possible to check if a `string` contains special `characters` or `numbers` from this `string` of `characters`:

```
"()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,'"
```

But at the same time ignore all results where these special `characters` are at the *end* of the `string`?

Examples:

```
"Hell,o" is False 
",.Hello" is False
"Whatc!hadoi66n" is False
"Hello," is True
"Hello,!'#" is True
```

Comment: use `str.endswith(...)` and `x in y` for a basis.

Comment: what did you try ?  Wecome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then `edit` your question to community guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: What about this string: "abcdefgh1ij!" There are two special characters in the "end" of the string. What will be the result True or False?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove all trailing special characters from the end of the string, and then check whether the resulting string and the special character set are disjoint.

```
def f(string, special="()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,'"):
    return {*string.rstrip(special)}.isdisjoint(special)
```

```
In [5]: f("Hell,o")
Out[5]: False

In [6]: f("Hello!")
Out[6]: True

In [7]: f("Hello,!'#")
Out[7]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

This regexp:

```
import re
re.match(r'[^()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,']*[()1234567890!?_@#$%^&*.,']*$', string)
```

The first part of the regexp requires the string to start with a sequence of characters that don't include the special characters. The second part matches a possibly empty sequence of special characters at the end.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/4VSDpB/1)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that example that allows multiple special characters at the end. I've updated.

Comment: Hi there, OP's question is not logically correct. What will be the result for this string: "abcdefgh1ij!"? It is clear that there are two special characters in the "end" of the string. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @ElisByberi Only `!` is at the end of the string, `1` is in the middle. So it should be `false`.

Comment: The middle character of the "abcdefgh1ij" is "f". In the start is "a" and in the end is "j". It is not normal to say that "1" is in the middle of the string.

Comment: I didn't mean the exact middle, I meant the middle portion of the string. According to his examples, all the special characters have to be together at the end.

Comment: It does not mention that they must be together regardless the test case. It is a word play, hahaha! It looks like a troll. The middle is just a middle not many middle.

Comment: The text says "at the end", and the examples make it clear what he means by that. He doesn't mean just the last character, he means in a sequence at the end.

Comment: There is only one end, one start, and one middle. That why we use these words.

Comment: That's why we ask people to provide examples, because it can be difficult to describe things in words.

Comment: OP maybe does not know English or he is just trolling. I am out! Have a nice day!